# CONDA_PYTHON_EXE environment variable macOS Catalina 10.15

Tags: linux, path, environment-variables, conda, anaconda3

In `$conda_python_exe` and also in `$PATH` environment variable I see the same path repeated twice, one surrounded by [].

```
CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/Users/student/Desktop/FRANCESCO/[/Users/student/Desktop/FRANCESCO]/bin/python
```

I can't install any tools using `conda install` on my Linux virtual machine.
I suppose there is a path issue, but I don't know why and how to resolve.

Thanks in advance

By googling, some say that path repeated in round bracket [] is not a problem, generally.